# Bazel is failing while building mediapipe for Android in Windows

Tags: android, bazel, mediapipe

I am trying to build a pose landmark detection program in android. For that reason, I am trying to create MediaPipe framework. I am working in Windows 11 and Bazel version 6.2.1.

I followed every steps as described in https://developers.google.com/mediapipe/framework/getting_started/install#installing_on_windows.

As per above link I used BAZEL_VC="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64" as this folder contains the files cl.exe, link.exe, lib.exe, ml64.exe.

But that caused following error
[image]

This is very much weird. The above mentioned path contains all required files (cl.exe, link.exe, lib.exe, ml64.exe), then why am I getting this error. Can someone please help me on this error.

Comment: Silly question perhaps, the `SET` to set environment described in the linked post was done in the same shell you tried to build in and took pictures of to post in the gallery here? `BAZEL_VC` needs to be set in the environment for the `bazel` process.

Answer (score 1):

The above implementation requires a compiler to build. You can refer http://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7393#issuecomment-462362527

Comment: I have Visual studio 2022 and I have set BAZEL_VC=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC initially. But it was throwing error "....The target you are compiling requires Visual C++ build tools..." Then I changed it to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64 still getting same error. Then I have set BAZEL_VS to the same path. But the same error.